# Mongodb connection closed error in azure function

Tags: azure-functions, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb

I am starting wtih azure function and azure cosmosdb (mongodb). I am trying to fetch data from cosmosdb on condition and write to cosmosdb if no data available for given condition, and after this perform some post operation. Flow of my azure funciton is like below

1. user input
2. pre-process input data
3. fetch from cosmosdb(mongodb) based on pre-processed data
4. if condition true insert into db
5. post processing

At 3rd step I have code to connect with cosmosdb using pymongo.

```
uri = "Mongodb connection string after creating cosmosdb" 
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
```

It gives error

> ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed

Do I need to add some permission to read write the db or some other setting that enable connection between `function app` and `cosmos db`.

Need help

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details. Hard to tell what's happening with only a single line of code. Can you show the connection string you're using (*obfuscated* - don't share the actual endpoint name or key)? It could possibly be something with that...

Comment: Does your Cosmos DB account configuration have IP Firewall or VNets?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta yes it do have firewall....  i have tried with public ip which not help. I am not able to find private IP which assigned by azure(correct me if i'm wrong). or do I need to create some Vnet and add both(function app + cosmos db) in it so that they can talk to each other.

Comment: but yes finding function IP is still black box for me

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, you are using a Firewall.

The problem is that Azure Functions has dedicated IPs only in certain hosting models, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale for full details.

If you have Firewall, you need to make sure that the IP the code is running on is whitelisted. Some hosting models do not provide a static IP, so that cannot be done.

Azure Cosmos DB provides a Firewall setting for allowing all Azure services too:
[image: Firewall settings]

Another alternative is Virtual Networks, but Virtual Networks are also not available to all Functions hosting plans.

Sounds like you might need Functions on Premium plan to support this feature if you don't want to open up to all Azure services.